# Setting the ACLs of a signed resumable URL with google cloud storage isn't working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using the following code to create a signed resumable url ([link here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers)). It works fine except for one thing: the ACLs are not being set on the object after I upload it with the created signed url.

```
public static void generateV4PutObjectSignedUrl(String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName) throws StorageException {
    // String projectId = "my-project-id";
    // String bucketName = "my-bucket";
    // String objectName = "my-object";

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();

    // Define Resource
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo
        .newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName))
        .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER),
                    Acl.of(new Acl.Project(Acl.Project.ProjectRole.OWNERS, "project-id"), Acl.Role.OWNER)))).build();

    // Generate Signed URL
    Map<String, String> extensionHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    extensionHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    URL url =
        storage.signUrl(
            blobInfo,
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(extensionHeaders),
            Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());

    System.out.println("Generated PUT signed URL:");
    System.out.println(url);
    System.out.println("You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:");
    System.out.println(
        "curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --upload-file my-file '"
            + url
            + "'");
      }
}
```

**How can I set the ACLs I want of a signed resumable url using the above code?**

Note: in non-signed url situations, the above way of setting the ACL works.

Comment: If you specify headers when you create a signed URL, the client must also specify the exact same headers. Try adding something similar to **-H "x-goog-acl:public-read"** to your curl example.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have tried setting the header `x-goog-acl:public-read` and it does work. However, I am trying to set multiple ACLs. The method you described only works for one predefined ACL.

Comment: As documented by Google, you can only set one ACL with that header: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-acls Options: 1) Use a bucket with a default ACL being what you want and then not use ACLs at all in the signed URL. 2) The XML interface supports more ACLs, but that sort of defeats/complicates signed URLs. 3) Create an event and use Cloud Functions to set the ACLs once an object has been uploaded.

Comment: @JohnHanley I see. Thank you for that detailed description. Do you have a suggestion on how to set the default ACL of a bucket to be what I have above? I want the owners of the project to have owner permissions and also for the object to be publicly readable.

Comment: I provided three options to consider.